# is there a problem with using pandas functions within a def scope

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run the code below, and the output that I get shows me nothing. My question is: is there a problem with using pandas functions within a def scope?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def readTrainingData():
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MohammadWasil/Predicting-Titanic-Survivors/master/train.csv"
  dadosTreino = pd.read_csv(url)
  return(dadosTreino)

def main():
    dfTrain = readTrainingData()
    dfTrain.head()

main()
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but it won't show you any output. Try printing it explicitly.

Comment: `return dfTrain.head()`

Comment: "is there a problem with using pandas functions within a def scope?"
No, no there isn't. What output where you *expecting*? Because there is nothing here that would output anything (e.g. a `print`)

Comment: The head function would show me the first five rows, correct? So, that's what I was expecting.

Comment: @CaioFernandes no the `.head` method returns a new `pandas.DataFrame` object consisting of the first 5 rows. Nowhere do you do anything that would output anything, e.g. a `print`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I got it. My question came out because, before trying this code, I had tested some panda functions and every time I used the head, it showed me what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Python's interpreter prompt is a REPL, or "read-eval-print loop". The "print" is key here: it will attempt to display the result of each calculation (as long as the "eval"uation produced something other than the special value `None`).

But this printing is only caused by the interpreter prompt, *not by the code itself*. So there is no implicit printing when you write code in a source file and run it with e.g. `python myfile.py`.

`dfTrain.head()` computes a value, but there is nothing to make it display. It also is not `return`ed from the function, so even if you tried to `import` the code from the interpreter prompt and call `main()` from there, it will evaluate to `None` and not print anything.